# Differences between python 2 and 3 in terms of "translate"

Tags: python

I have question about translate function in python 3
(I am studying from a book that's for python 2)

In Python2, we do:

```
from string import maketrans 
table = maketrans ('cs', 'kz')

"this is an incredible test".translate(table)
"this is an incredible test".translate(table, ' ')
```

How do we do it in python 3?  I know that:

```
table = str.maketrans ('cs', 'kz')
"this is an incredible test".translate(table)
```

will works

But I can't seem to figure it out how to do the:

```
"this is an incredible test".translate(table, ' ')
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Have you read the relevant documentation?

Comment: ermm... what do you mean the relevant documentation? (sorry, I am still new to programming)

Comment: [the relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) - basically googling for Python + *name-of-function* will almost always bring up the official Python documentation - then you just have to be careful it's for the right major version (3 rather than 2)

Comment: oh yeah that.  I did remember seeing it before, perhaps I didn't pay too much attention.  But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3 the *deletechars* are added as the third argument to `maketrans`, rather than as the second argument to `translate`. In both cases chars can be mapped to `None` when manually creating a unicode mapping dictionary to pass to `maketrans`)

```
# Python3
table = str.maketrans ('cs', 'kz', ' ')
"this is an incredible test".translate(table)
```

gives:
'thizizaninkredibletezt'